# Next-Auth Profile custom typings

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I'm having a problem with typescript and Next Auth type definitions.
According to the docs I should be able to add my custom types to the NextAuth modules and so I did for the `Profile` interface in the `next-auth.d.ts`. It does add the type when I do `profile.groups` but when I want to destructure it typescript complains that this type doesn't exists on Profile type... Any idea what I'm missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me. I'm using the same project structure and it should work as expected. What version of TS are you using? There are some issues related to this on git.

Comment: Node 16.18, Typescript 4.8.4. I'm using also T3 stack if it matters

Comment: Does it work elsewhere in your project? And does it compile with errors if you force the destructuring ?

Comment: Will double check tomorrow. 
One thing that comes to my mind that there might be a problem with custom DB adapter types? Im using this one for redis https://github.com/quanhua92/next-auth-ioredis-adapter-example/blob/main/lib/IORedisAdapter.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that you can't destructure `undefined` in JS/TS.

As you might have noticed, `profile` parameter can be `undefined`. Since this variable can take the `undefined` value, typescript does not want to see it as "destructurable" **because it can not destructure undefined value**.

You could try to check for `undefined` first and then cast the `profile` as `Profile` instead of `Profile | undefined`.

Comment: Well, this is actually true and correct! ahhh well silly me forgetting about fundamental check for such :D.
This works, thanks!
```
signIn ({ profile }) {
      if (!profile) return false
      
      const { groups = [] } = profile;

      return groups.some(Boolean);
    },
```